# No sound option except Dummy Output on Dell Latitude D630

Tags: sound, dell, 15.04

I have a Dell Latitude D630. When I reinstalled Ubuntu 15.04 from a DVD after an update, it left my laptop inoperable. Now the only sound option under audio is "Dummy Output". I have tried advice from other websites, but nothing helps. The options listed here do not apply to my 15.04 problem.

Comment: so that we don't repeat the same suggestions you've already tried, can you please list the failed solutions? thanks!

Comment: do you have a file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`?

Comment: sometimes (hopefully) all you need to run is `sudo service pulseaudio stop` then `sudo alsa force-reload` and `sudo service pulseaudio start`

Comment: if there is no service found you can run this instead `sudo killall pulseaudio` then `sudo alsa force-reload` and `pulseaudio`

Comment: Tried it...here is what it gave me:

Comment: russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo killall pulseaudio
[sudo] password for russellhoo: 
russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo killall pulseaudio
russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ ^C
russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$

Comment: I do have  /etc/pulse/default.pa

Comment: That's good you have the file. I think you can force-load alsa or something similar, run the command `sudo alsa` and see the options given. It looks like none of your sound modules loaded in the first place. See if there is an option for something like `sudo alsa force-load` or load or something.

Comment: if not, you'll have to run the command `alsamixer` press F6 and press down arrow and press enter press the right arrow until you see the automute option and change it to off by pressing the up arrow go back to the left and check out all your volumes and adjust them. Your sound may work now. Then, reboot if it's still not working.

Comment: This is what I get:  russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo alsa force-load
Usage: /sbin/alsa {unload|reload|force-unload|force-reload|suspend|resume}

Comment: I am not sure how to run alsamixer

Comment: go for force unload  and as for alsamixer, open a terminal type `alsamixer` and press enter

Comment: russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall  alsa-base alsa-utils linux-sound-base`. That should re-install ALSA. Then restart PulseAudio using `sudo service pulseaudio restart`.

Comment: russell@russell-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo service pulseaudio restart
Failed to restart pulseaudio.service: Unit pulseaudio.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Comment: russell@russell-Latitude-D630:~$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory

Comment: If you boot your system from a live key, do you get sound? If not, this might be a bug.

Comment: I do get a single beep.

Comment: Not sure what a "live key" is, but I get a single beep when I start the computer.

Comment: It's the removable storage media (probably a DVD or Flashdrive) that has a bootable version of Ubuntu. You probably used it to install Ubuntu. If you boot from a key, can you play sounds? If you have any audio CDs handy, perhaps you should use one to test the system.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.bak
sudo cp /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf.bak  # backup alsa-base.conf
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

This will open alsa-base.conf for editing in nano text editor. Scroll down to the bottom of alsa-base.conf and add this new line to the bottom:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m42
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes you made to alsa-base.conf. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

Next run the following command:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

The next time you reboot check to find out if the changes you made held up after a reboot.

Comment: yes, I just cam across a blogpost that backs this method up http://nathansheffield.com/wordpress/installing-ubuntu-linux-on-a-dell-latitude-d630/ I don't know if it's needed but was suggested to install this `sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules` kind of outdated though

Comment: THe option "options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m22" stayed after the reboot, but I still have "dummy output".

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it again with `dell-m42` instead of `dell-m22`.

Comment: m42 did save. When I run "sudo force-reload" I get: russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$ sudo alsa force-reload  
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$

Comment: When I run: "sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules" I get: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules
russellhoo@russellhoo-Latitude-D630:~$

Comment: Thanks for your efforts...I am grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses ALSA as a sound driver, but PulseAudio acts as a man in the middle, interfacing between ALSA and the various programs on the computer. PulseAudio is supposed to be able to, for lack of a nicer term, "hijack" the sound card. However to to so requires that PulseAudio be the only program accessing the sound card directly.

The first thing I would do is try restarting PulseAudio using `pulseaudio -k`.

If there are other programs accessing the sound card, they need to either stop accessing the card, or be shut down. The best way to find out which programs are accessing the sound card is to run `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*`. You should see the names and PIDs of any programs using your sound card. If you see anything other than PulseAudio, you can shut it down using the kill command. Assuming the problematic PIDs are 12345 and 67890, you can use `kill 12345 67890`. If the programs accessing your sound card are being run by some user other than you, you may need to use sudo to run kill with root privileges.

PS: The Arch Linux wiki has a [very detailed article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting) on troubleshooting PulseAudio. If none of the above works for you, maybe something there will.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from any of the Linux LiveCDs as @TSJNachos117 suggested in the comments.

On my **Toshiba Tecra A8** I tried **Puppy Linux 4**. I couldn't hear any sound when I booted from the **Puppy Linux 4**, but when I rebooted to my Ubuntu 15.04 the sound was back. And in the audio settings there were *"Built-in Speakers"* instead of *"Dummy Output"* as my speakers.